# Realizando o Submit Form usando C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, .net

Existe o seguinte formulário de login em HTML

```
  <form action="/Home/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f" method="post">
     <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="W3ndyLx5kkFIy_QKjOGhEYQoHFtF4kIMFxLIG42t2r5tJJKwnzCy1iMmLw8SFH6yIm7DnHiQqKAmOhKS-PSDnDDzNcfjxNWCCEDthaA5mAE1" />    
     <div  style="width: 40%; margin-left:36%;" >

    <h2>Login</h2>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Usuario">Usu&#225;rio</label>
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Usuário Necessário" id="Usuario" name="Usuario" placeholder="Digite seu usuário" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Usuario" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Senha">Senha</label>
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Senha Necessária" id="Senha" name="Senha" placeholder="Digite sua senha" type="password" />
         <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Senha" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" style="width: 100px" class="btn btn-success" value="Entrar">Entrar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

estou tentando realizar o login desta página usando C#:

```
    private string Realizar(string url, string Usuario, string Senha)
    {
        string resultado = string.Empty;
        string strPost = "Usuario=" + Usuario + "&Senha=" + Senha + "&ReturnUrl=//";
        Stream myWriter = null;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        byte[] send = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strPost);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = send.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        try
        {
            myWriter = request.GetRequestStream();
            myWriter.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            myWriter.Close();
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if(response == null)
        {
            return "Erro";
        }
        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            resultado = reader.ReadToEnd();

            reader.Close();
        }

        return resultado;

    }
```

No entanto, ao executar a função, retorna a seguinte exceção: O servidor remoto retornou um erro:

> (500) Erro Interno do Servidor.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: A rota /Home/Login está sendo apontada para o método **privado** Realizar?

Comment: está na variável "url"

Comment: Você tem um Controller chamado Home, com um Método Chamado Login?

Comment: é uma pagina externa, não pertence ao projeto principal, o objetivo é realizar um login de pagina usando uma outra aplicação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se no html existe o input `__RequestVerificationToken`

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="W3ndyLx5kkFIy_QKjOGhEYQoHFtF4kIMFxLIG42t2r5tJJKwnzCy1iMmLw8SFH6yIm7DnHiQqKAmOhKS-PSDnDDzNcfjxNWCCEDthaA5mAE1" />
```

Provavelmente a Action deve ter o atributo `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`

O objetivo deste atributo é impedir o acesso a sua aplicação por requisições http originadas de outras aplicações. Garantindo que apenas as views de sua aplicação consigam submeter requisições para a Action "decorada" com este atributo.

Ao tentar submeter uma requisição http para um Action com este atributo, sem enviar o código gerado para o input `__RequestVerificationToken` ou informando um valor errado é gerado erro 500 no servidor.

Para mais informações:

[Preventing Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Attacks in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks)
[XSRF/CSRF Prevention in ASP.NET MVC and Web Pages](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages)